# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input While doing JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

HTML & PHP:

```
<select id="package">
    <?php $package_size_array = array('size_a' => 70, 'size_b' => 90, 'size_c' => 130); ?>
    <option value="size" id="<?php echo json_encode($package_size_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>">Size</option>
    <!--Some more <option>s here...-->
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('select#package').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).children(':selected').attr('id');
        alert(JSON.parse(id)); /* Line 217. in functions.js file */
    });
});
```

Problem: Chrome and probably other browsers' console prints:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input functions.js:217
(anonymous function) functions.js:217
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4371
elemData.handle
```

Comment: Why would you need to JSON.parse() the id?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this code?  `id` is just a string, it's not a JSON object.

Comment: Because the <option> id contains JSON encoded php array. I want get back my PHP array through JavaScript and JSON unserializing.

Comment: @David: _"JavaScript Object Notation Object"_? JSON is never an "Object", rather an string. (Nitpicking, I know)

Comment: @TomsBugna: Can you show us the HTML resulting from your php? It's also a bad idea to use the `id` attribute to transfer data like that...

Comment: @Cerbrus Then what's the better idea to do it?

Comment: That is a syntax error but I don't see a syntax error in your javascript... maybe something about the json. what if you just alerted 'hello', does that work?

Comment: Don't use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` -- it will put newlines in the output, which will really mess up the ID.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Very nitpicking.  Regardless of the terminology, JSON is a serialized object.  Deserializing it assumes that the string is a serialized object in the first place.  I'm curious what `id` actually contains in this case.

Comment: The syntax error is because he's using double quotes in `id="JSON"` and the JSON also contains double quotes, so his quotes are all messed up.

Comment: @Barmar this doesn't change the fact that still it is not working properly.

Comment: if you enclose your id string with `'` instead of `"` the browser will not break with this example data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the data you are converting to JSON consists solely of a Boolean or a Number, the resulting JSON is going to contain `"` characters.

You are using `"` characters to delimit your ID attribute value, so the first one in the data is going to end the attribute prematurely.

This would be much more obvious if you examined the data you were sending to the browser (with `view > source`) instead of just looking at the PHP.

You need to convert the text representation of the JSON to an HTML representation of it.

```
id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($package_size_array)); ?>"
```

You should also remove JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, it is useful for debugging but inefficient in practice and new lines aren't a good fit for attribute values.

---

That said, using JSON for an ID value is a terrible idea. If you want to store arbitrary data on an element, use [a `data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) (you'll still need to convert the text to HTML though!)

Comment: A nice thing about storing JSON in a `data-*` attribute is that jQuery will automatically decode it for you.

Comment: Take out `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, I think that makes things even worse.

Comment: in chrome running `document.getElementById('package').options[0].id` in console on the provided php file gives the expected json in its full glory. So doesnt necessarily break things, altho i share your concern for multiline html attributes